# Shared photo library. Why photo location information is not shared?

Tags: icloud, photos, family-sharing

Using Photos Family Shared Library between me and my family. I would assume that when somebody in the family add photo to Shared Library all meta-data of the photo would be included as well. However photos that my daughter added to Shared Library don't have location information when I see them on my computer. Is it configurable somewhere or is it a feature / limitation of the Shared Library?